# How can I deal with an indeterminate number of input FormControls in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have an angular app in which I want to enter an unknown number of entries, say names, to a list.

I want to compile the list of names into an array. I want to be able to show an input element to allow the user to enter a name.

Every time they enter a name I want it to be validated and added to the names array, and I want a new blank input field to appear below it.

I assume I need an array of `FormControl`s in my `FormGroup`. If so, how do I refer to each element by form control name in my HTML form?

Comment: This sounds like a job for FormArray..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need your form model to have a `formArray` that will be your name array:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ names: this.formBuilder.array([]) })
```

Suposing `form` is your root form group.

Then, you can have a button to add a new name control to your form array:

```
<button type="button" (click)="addNameControl()">Add Name</button>
```

Your click function will be something like:

```
addNameControl(): void { (this.form.get('names') as FormArray).push(this.formBuilder.control('') }
```

If you want to validate you can do it on the submit function, iterating over the controls and checking values, or using `Validators` when declaring the control.

Your final html would look like:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="names">
    <div *ngFor="let name of names.controls">
      <input type="text" [formControl]="i">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, if your `FormGroup` name is `myForm`, then make it public you can use this in the html:

```
    <span *ngFor="let element of controlsNames">
              <input id="{{element}}"
                     type="text"
                     formControlName="myForm.get(element)"
                     class="form-control" />
    </span>
```